# How to run automatically Excel macros?

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a cricket sheet in excel. I have also created a macro which is used to display a message when overs bowled are equal to 20 (A T-20 Match). My problem is that when the over get to 20 no message is shown unless I press the shortcut key. Is there anything which I can do so that whenever overs reach to 20 a message automatically displays.

My code is:

```
Sub Innings()

If Range("H43") = 20# Then

MsgBox "Innings Completed"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `worksheet change` event, do you know where is it?

Comment: whats your file extension? And, from where H43 cell gets value?

Comment: Extension is .xlsx. Basically cell H43 is sum function that count the overs.

Comment: someone is answering and onto it. Wish your purpose served then.

Comment: I hope. Anyway thank you for your precious time.

Comment: OK. Thanks to Everyone who have alloted their time to answer my question. I have got my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gary's Student's code is working well. You just need to write Worksheet_Change and Worksheet_Calculate to the List1 not to the Module1. I add a picture.

[image]

Comment: Hw to open List1. There are 3 Modules of which Module 3 contains my code.

Answer (score 3):

Include the following macros in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Call Innings
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H43")) Is Nothing Then
        Call Innings
    End If
End Sub
```

Because they are worksheet code macros, they are very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try them on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macros will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macros:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

Macros must be enabled for this to work!

Comment: Hey Gary on entering the code error occurs. "Expected End Sub"

Comment: Hey gary on entering the code error occur "Expected End Sub".

Comment: Gary thanx for your help but I still can't figure out. Should I send you the sheet so you correct the problem? It will be very helpful.

Comment: Gary, Please reply. I have to submit this sheet to smeone.

Comment: This Forum does not support file sharing.